# Compare and match two audio files with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pyaudio

I am trying to compare a recorded audio sample from a microphone with a stored audio file, my goal is if the recorded audio file matches any part of the stored audio, what will be the simplest way to do so?

Comment: Hi AmabGhosh, What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://github.com/QED0711/audio_analyzer -- this

Comment: I wanted something simple and lightweight that I can run on small footprint device like raspberry pi

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail about what you want to achieve?  In general, comparing two audio samples programmatically is a complex operation, maybe involving moving to the frequency domain.  (Also note that if you want someone to be notified of your comment, add the @<username> to the comment ;) )

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am very new to this community don't know anyone. So my intention is to recognize an audio pattern, not human voice, so I have a ".wav" file of 10 audio samples, and I recorded 10 seconds of sound, now I want to compare the recorded sound patterns that how much it matches with the stored already stored sound, like for example if any portion of the recorded sound is matched with the stored audio sample I will do some action!